# Java read system input in while loop

Tags: java, input

here is a very simple code, in which i am trying to take input from keyboard in a loop. For every input, the loop is automatically running two extra times and taking the values 13 and 10, no matter what i give as input. can you please point out what i am doing wrong.

CODE:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    boolean loop_cond=true;
    int n=1;

    while(loop_cond==true)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.print("input : ");

            n=br.read();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.print(n+"\n");

    }
}  // end Main
```

OUTPUT :

```
input : 6
54
input : 13
input : 10
input : 9
57
input : 13
input : 10
input : 1
49
input : 13
input : 10
input :
```

Comment: 13 is a carriage return and 10 is a newline. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ascii+7

Comment: I believe your program also reads in the "Enter/New line" character

Comment: Understood it. But how to prevent this ? i only want to run the loop only once for every input i provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are probably \r\n values. Try Scanner to take in values.

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sudhanshu. It is working just the way i want. But can you tell me how to implement this in BufferedReader ?

Comment: use readLine() instead of read(). readLine() returns String so you might have to convert it to int.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
n=br.read();
```

to

```
n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

But I would recommend you to use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to avoid the Integer conversion.